# Typescript overriding overloaded method in subclass - incorrect type

Tags: typescript

[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwMJxAB3gbwCh5j4BbAewDcQAKYASzjABd7yA7ALnnYFdSARiBgBKbpXL1gAbiIkK1Gs1gBzEM27JmMeuxVj4EqbIC+BAmA5b4AfXI6VuqBACyVBAF4MWbADpsMOTMQQCe2CC+CiCyFtCo3iA4AKIAHtpQ8CBpIOzAaJiJuIQkZO50jOCsHNx8gsIGRjJyxFFKquqa2rr64pJNJa0MTFVcPPxCMPAAPvBaOnoi+M0l8PQAZvBKYSDkG0OVbOzwHifwAORz3WeLxSt3cMy8MEd2Dk6u7r5gzhBKABb0ZAAGng+xYhxEsjuxDM0PgDyeL3s9Ec7GcbmoXx+-0BILBI0hyzMJiAA)

I'm attempting to extend an overloaded method in a subclass, but Typescript doesn't seem to be using the right argument types when calling the original function:

```
declare class Creep {
    move(direction: number): void;
    move(target: string): void;
}

const _originalMove = Creep.prototype.move;

class CreepExtra extends Creep {
    move(direction: number): void;
    move(target: string): void;
    move(direction: number | string) {
        if (typeof direction === 'string') {
            return _originalMove.call(this, direction);
        }
        return _originalMove.call(this, direction);
    }
}
```

Results in this error (for the direction argument of the last call):

```
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.(2345)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in typescript?

Comment: It's a design limitation; [the `--strictBindCallApply` functionality](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#strictbindcallapply) introduced in TS3.2 [doesn't work well for generic/overloaded functions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028#issuecomment-429334450).  To work around it you could just widen `_originalMove` to a non-overloaded version before calling, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGPRJw) (or asserted like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgglbw)).

Comment: Does that address your needs? If so, I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  Note that the example here is a bit *too* minimal since overloads are best avoided when practical, and so there's no reason why someone wouldn't write both functions like `move(directionOrTarget: number | string) : void` instead.  It would be nice if the example were not so easily unified, like maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYkZEN).

Comment: Thanks, I was mainly looking to see if it's my mistake, a known issue or one I should report. Your first example is useful, I'll probably do that as I don't like using `as` if I can possibly avoid it.

Comment: The base Creep class is provided by the environment (in this case the game [screeps](http://screeps.com)) which is why I have to extend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of TypeScript. The support for strongly-typed [`Function.prototype.call()` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) that was [introduced in TypeScript 3.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#strictbindcallapply) doesn't work well for generic or overloaded functions.  See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028#issuecomment-429334450) in [microsoft/TypeScript#27028](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028), the pull request that implemented this support.

When you directly call an overloaded function, the compiler will select the most  appropriate call signature.  But when you start dealing with overloaded function *types*, the compiler essentially gives up and just picks one of the call signatures without paying attention to whether it's appropriate for the eventual use case.  This is usually the last call signature (although sometimes it's the first, I guess?)  It's not well documented; see [microsoft/TypeScript#43187](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43187) for information.

In your case that means that the `Function.prototype.call()` on `_originalMove` behaves as if it has just the last call signature, of type `(target: string) => void;`.  And that's fine for one of your calls but not fine for the other.  Oh well.

---

A workaround here would be for you to explicitly widen the type of `_originalMove` to the single relevant call signature before calling `call()` on it.  That is, the following is considered a safe assignment:

```
  const om: (direction: number) => void = _originalMove;
```

because `_originalMove` has both call signatures.  And at that point, `om.call()` will allow the second parameter to be of type `number`:

```
  return om.call(this, direction);
```

And everything just works:

```
class CreepExtra extends Creep {
  move(direction: number): void;
  move(target: string): void;
  move(direction: number | string) {
    if (typeof direction === 'string') {
      return _originalMove.call(this, direction);
    }
    const om: (direction: number) => void = _originalMove;
    return om.call(this, direction); // okay
  }
}
```

Hooray!

---

Note well:

In the example shown here your overloaded method  has two call signatures differing only the the type of the single function parameter; such call signatures can be easily unified via [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types):

```
declare class Creep {
  move(directionOrTarget: number | string): void;
}

const _originalMove = Creep.prototype.move;

class CreepExtra extends Creep {
  move(targetOrDirection: number | string) {
    return _originalMove.call(this, targetOrDirection);
  }
}
```

Since overloads and type inference don't really play nicely together, as shown in the first part of this answer, if you have the opportunity to remove overloads without sacrificing anything else, then you should take it.  Presumably your actual use case isn't as simple as the example code shown here, but it's a good exercise for everyone to check whether the benefits of overloads outweigh their disadvantages.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-IetGer2OYXWURa1p4iWAySxGSyeLyEtDMDKFSqAIasvieeDY2K3T6tAGQ10I3YzYmvqmO0TuljABFabdk6s03CTuGeAqMZLsSX8fUiWqNdTdvtR+P6XKLTmG3EYkA)